# keyEquivalent for non-alphanumeric keys (AIR/AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, air, keyboard-shortcuts

thanks in advance,

I'd like to use NativeMenuItem.keyEquivalent to set a keyboard shortcut for some menu items. Some of them use keys like Insert, Delete, Backspace etc

How do I set keyEquivalent for these characters? keyEquivalent is a string so I'm not sure how to set it up like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Insert, Delete, etc for keyEquivalent, only letters and numbers.  You can still add the string "insert" to the keyEquivalent property and it'll appear in the menu, it just won't automatically respond to the keyboard press.

What you can do instead is listen for those key presses using a standard keyboard event listener, and that listener can either invoke the menu item by dispatching the Event.SELECT event from the menu item, or you can directly call whatever function the menu item would normally have called.

```
item.keyEquivalent = "insert";
item.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onItemSelect);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);
...
// menu item handler
private function onItemSelect(e:Event)
{
    trace("item was selected.");
}

// keyboard handler
private function onKeyUp(e:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.INSERT)
        item.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.SELECT));
}
```

Comment: So close, but this also causes pressing the `i` key to trigger the `Event.SELECT` event as well.

Comment: It's probably the keyEquivalent property just grabbing the first character from "insert".  You might be able to get around it by using an invisible character as the first character of the string, but I don't know for sure.  I think a worst case scenario you just don't set the keyEquivalent property and add the "Insert" text to the menu yourself.